# Nginx showing 404 no matter the config

Tags: nginx

I am having a bit of an issue at the moment with the nginx. No matter what config I make, I will get 404 page. 
I am following instructions for setting up nginx for laravel.

Folder where the project is located is **/var/www/smuvajse**, and main **index.php** is located into **public** folder (full path would be **/var/www/smuvajse/public**)

This is my config file:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/smuvajse/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name ip_of_the_instac;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
         }

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php7.0-fpm:
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```

Comment: What is in `nginx` error.log?

Answer (score 0):

change `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;` and reload nginx and it should solve the issue.

Comment: Made the change, but I am still getting 404 :/